# Creating Maintainable Xml structure for a relational database

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd, xmldatasource

I am not trying to save dataset or datatable to a xml file rather create a xml structure for saving related data? For example i would like to know how below data could be in a xml file

#### User

```
UserId
Username
Password
```

#### Roles

```
RoleId
UserId [FK]
CreatedOn
```

will it look like this

```
<User userid="" username="" password="">
<Roles id="">
 <Name></Name>
 <Description></Description>
</Roles>
</User>
```

which structure would be best to use xml files as DB

Comment: Read up on ORM, and maybe take a look at this related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412748/orm-entity-xml-serialization

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer seriously i got no time for getting in depth for just designing a structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to consider implementing the XML in a more normalized manner, similar to how you would do so with a relational database.  For instance in your current solution you would be required to type out the entire role structure within every user such as

```
<User userid="1" username="user01" password="password">
   <Roles id="1">
      <Name>Role 1</Name>
      <Description>This is Role 1</Description>
   </Roles>
</User>
<User userid="2" username="user02" password="password">
   <Roles id="1">
      <Name>Role 1</Name>
      <Description>This is Role 1</Description>
   </Roles>
</User>
```

A normalized structure could look like the following

```
<Roles>
   <Role id="1">
      <Name>Role 1</Name>
      <Description>This is Role 1</Description>
   </Role>
</Roles>

<User id="1" username="user01" password="password">
   <Roles>
      <Role>1</Role>
   </Roles>
</User>
<User id="2" username="user02" password="password">
   <Roles>
      <Role>1</Role>
   </Roles>
</User>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Perfect that's exactly i wanted, some code to show how to do i